# how to get NetBios Name for other ip address from iOS app in Local network

Tags: objective-c, ios10, wifi, netbios

How to get **NetBios Name** for other ip address from **iOS** wifi scan sample app in Local network where my device is connected and I am getting all connected device ip address?

**Mac-OS** i am using this code.

-(NSString *) runCommand: (NSString *) commandToRun {

```
NSTask *task;
task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath: @"/bin/sh"];

NSArray *arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      @"-c" ,
                      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", commandToRun],
                      nil];
NSLog(@"run command: %@",commandToRun);
[task setArguments: arguments];

NSPipe *pipe;
pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
[task setStandardOutput: pipe];

NSFileHandle *file;
file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

[task launch];

NSData *data;
data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];

NSString *output;
output = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

return output; }
```

command is **Mac-Mini:~ Test$ smbutil status 10.0.0.19**

**output : Using IP address of 10.0.0.19: 10.0.0.19**

**Workgroup:** A 
**Server:** TestLAP_004

like [Fing App](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/fing-network-scanner/id430921107?mt=8)

Comment: I am using NSTask for Mac-OS but no idea for iOS.

Comment: Using Command Mac-Mini:~ Abc$ smbutil status 10.0.0.19

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution ?

Comment: No, i didn't get any solution